do Monophysitism and Nestorianism follow the Peshitta Or does it contradict their beliefs
It like what title says it simple.
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Peshitta didn't explain well

you need to be slightly more specific. People can "guess" what exactly you meant, but providing a few extra sentences and a quote helps. (I don't understand why people don't like to click on links... but hey) Also, where is the question mark?

@Wyrsa The comments on individual questions is not the place to complain about the community, see the acceptable comments policy. Let's leave that for the Meta discussion you started.

Answer based on my understanding/research/knowledge of the Eastern Orthodox Church.

What is Monophysitism? According to multiple sources, Monophysitism is a heresy that started when some rejected the Council of Chalcedon. (OrthodoxWiki, OrthodoxNet, the OCA, etc)

Monophysitism is a Christological heresy that originated in the 5th century A.D. Its chief proponent was the monk Eutyches, who stated that in the person of Jesus Christ the human nature was absorbed into the divine nature like a cube of sugar dissolves in a cup of water. Therefore, Christ was left with only one nature, the Divine (Greek mono- one, physis - nature).
... In their struggle against Nestorianism, some theologians went as far as the other extreme. They denied completely the presence of human nature in Jesus Christ, accepting only one Divine Nature in one Divine Hypostasis. Thus, they are called Monophysites (believers in one nature). Condemned at the Fourth Ecumenical Council in Chalcedon, Monophysites accused the Council and the Church of restoring Nestorianism.
OrthodoxWiki


What is Nestorianism? According to multiple sources, Nestorianism is heresy.

Nestorianism is a Christological heresy which originated in the Church in the 5th century out of an attempt to rationally explain and understand the incarnation of the divine Logos, the Second Person of the Holy Trinity as the man Jesus Christ. Nestorianism teaches that the human and divine essences of Christ are separate and that there are two persons, the man Jesus Christ and the divine Logos, which dwelt in the man. Thus, Nestorians reject such terminology as "God suffered" or "God was crucified", because they believe that the man Jesus Christ suffered. Likewise, they reject the term Theotokos (Giver of birth to God) for the Virgin Mary, using instead the term Christotokos (giver of birth to Christ) or Anthropotokos (giver of birth to a man).
OrthodoxWiki


What is the Peshitta?
The Peshitta Old Testament (or Peshitta Tanakh) was translated from the Hebrew to Aramaic somewhere around the time of Christ. Some scholars say it may have been as late as 100AD, so the LXX (Septuagint) OT is older, having the books of Moses translated around 250 BC and the rest of the books finished in the following 100 years.
The Peshitta New Testament: The Syrian Church of the East states that the Aramaic New Testament manuscripts were hand delivered to them by the Apostles or their direct associates (with the exception of 2nd Peter, 2nd & 3rd John, Jude, & Revelation). Those 5 books were later back-translated from the Greek into the Aramaic. (Significantly later, some saints didn't even have the book of Revelation)
We can basically call the Peshitta a version of the Bible. And it does have differences between versions. The interesting thing about the Peshitta is that it has word play and looks more like an original language document than the greek translations. But no fundamental doctrine shifts.
Now the basis of Orthodox Christian teaching is the Holy Tradition of the Church, made infallible by the Holy Spirit, of which the Bible is a crucial part of.

Now for the answer to the question.
From the position of the Eastern Orthodox Church the answer is "No", it does not support their beliefs.
When I said previously that the Peshitta was incomplete for a period of time, it took them until the 6th century to have it all together. Many of the Ecumenical councils happened before this did. Many other heresies were refuted without the Peshitta being complete. (Or even our modern Bible)
What you have to understand though, is that the current Orthodox doctrine (dyophysitism) was determined by an ecumenical council, which by definition can’t err. Questioning them affects not only Christology, but also the Ecclesiology of the church as a whole. They used the scriptures that they had. And even in the "incomplete" state, the Peshitta supports the current understanding, teaching, and tradition of the Eastern Orthodox church.

The question is whether the Monophysite and Nestorian branches accept the Peshitta, not whether mainstream branches do. Your judgement on the heretical status of those positions is off-topic for this question, so I will be editing that out. Now while you're right that the Peshitta is a translation (better than version) of the Bible, that doesn't mean it is entirely irrelevant to theology - no translation is perfect and there could be passages in the Peshitta which more readily lead to these theologies than either the original Biblical languages do, or than other translations do.

However now that I've edited out the off-topic parts, I see there's really nothing of substance in this answer. We need more details than what you've written.

@curiousdannii I pointed out that mainstream christianity would say that those two doctrines are incompatible with the Peshitta. Without that in my answer, my answer has no content

Edited. On a side note, if someone edits an answer and it then gets downvoted... is the editor or the OP the one that gets the reputation point reduction?

Much more detailed, thank you.
